# installing other apps(ipa) from within app iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, installation

I want to install other apps within one of my app,just like what appstore does, when you click install and confirm the app starts downloading on the springboard.I had tried with openURL, but seems it does not fulfill my requirements. Is there any other way out to achieve this one.please suggest.

thanks in advance.
Manoj

Comment: Are you talking about doing this on jailbroken devices or all devices?

Comment: For any legitimate use, please don't try to circumvent the standard process used to install applications.

Comment: @skorulis: this app is strictly not for jailbroken devices.

Comment: @zneak: So you are trying to say there is no other way to achieve this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security sandbox on stock OS iOS devices does not allow the installation of other apps.  You can only write non-executable files to a few directories within your own apps sandbox.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this or any sample code would be helpful.

Comment: What is there to elaborate, what you want can not be done in the official SDK. Like hotpaw2 wrote you can only write to the directories with in you applications sandbox, and there is no way to execute any apps from there.

Comment: @rckoenes: this is basically an enterprise app, can I query to apple's enterprise team.